# Check if two continous Uppercase letter exists php

Tags: php, regex

I have a situation . I need some regex which will check if more than two uppercase characters exits. Lets take a look at example

```
 Input  = "HelloTest"
 Output = "H ello T est" 

 Input  = "HelloTHISisTest";
 output = "H ello THIS is T est"
```

logic is i am trying to break words whenever i find a uppercase letter . but if more than two uppercase letters will be in continous form than it will not break.

Rules are 
words will not break if

1. they will have more than two consecutive uppercase characters ,
2. they are consecutive lowercase characters

   Any help?

Comment: That logic seems a little wonky. What about `AmISure`? Is that `Am I Sure` or `Am IS ure`? How can you distinguish those two? Or should it be `AmIsure`? Then shouldn't that break into `Am Isure`?

Comment: For AmISure it would be Am IS ure and AmIsure would be Am I sure.

Comment: Then why isn't it `H ello THIS is T est`? How is that logical? What's the unifying rule here? I can't see it.

Comment: O yes.Sorry for confusion  i have updated it .

Comment: I think you need to do some coding instead of regex like make a function which takes that string and returns your expected string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$input = "HelloTHISisTest";
$output = preg_replace('/([A-Z]+)/', ' \1 ', $input);
$output = trim($output);
var_dump($output);

# output will be:
# string(20) "H ello THIS is T est"
```

See online fiddle http://ideone.com/OaQz3N

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following:

```
(?:[A-Z]{2,}+|[a-z]{2,}+|[A-Z][a-z]++)(?!$)
```

And replace with `$0` .

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/yH0cP3/1)

The regex first tries to match any consecutive uppercase characters or lowercase characters and at last resort try to match a single uppercase followed by at least 1 lowercase character, all 3 of them without backtracking and a negative lookahead at the end to prevent matching the last 'word' (so an extra space is not added).

---

For the edited question, you can use the following to get the new output:

```
(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[A-Z])(?=[a-z])
```

And replace with a space.

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/yH0cP3/2)

Comment: @Creator Yea... all for nought since you edited your question...

Comment: o yes!!! Thanks to @deceze for notifying. Mind had already written it . But what to say man !! Merry Xms .

Comment: @Creator I think you just need to clarify the rules of your original question. Don't just get bent if a user critizes your logic. You could surely say that consecutive characters should be kept together if 1. they are consecutive uppercase characters, 2. they are consecutive lowercase characters 3. if the previous two fail, then if the first character is uppercase and the remaining are lowercase.

Comment: yes . I did not explain it better before. ANyway have updated . Coz you got my logic. Thanks

Comment: @Creator Well, now your example output does not match the logic statement... The first output should be `"Hello Test"` and the second `"Hello THIS is Test"`

Answer (score 0):

You can match:

```
"([A-Z])(?=[A-Z])"
```

And replace with:

```
"\1 "
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=[A-Z])(?=[a-z])|(?<![A-Z])(?=[A-Z])
```

Try this.See demo.Replace by `space`

https://regex101.com/r/gQ3kS4/36